# Как реализовать переподключение к БД в ооп-стиле php?

Tags: php, база-данных, ооп, mysqli

Доброго времени суток. Пишу свой класс, наследуюсь от класса `mysqli` с целью прикрутить метод `query()` с автоматическим переподключением к базе, если соединение было разорвано (например, если `mysql server has gone away`). Как вообще можно переподключиться к базе из одного из методов класса-наследника `mysqli`? В процедурном стиле это выглядело бы примерно так:

```
if(mysqli_ping($d)===true){
    return mysqli_query($d, $query);
}else{
    mysqli_close($d);
    $d = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    return mysqli_query($d, $query);
}
```

Но как реализовать переподключение в ооп-стиле?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что нельзя переподключиться к базе в рамках одного экземпляра `mysqli`. Т.е. Вам нужно разрушить старый объект и создать новый, точно также, как Вы переприсваиваете значение переменной `$d`

Comment: Наследоваться от mysql очень неблагодарная тема. Я раньше пытался, бросьте это дело. Лучше так не делайте. Лучше написать адаптер, который внутри себя будет хранить ссылку на текущее соединение  и перед запросом проверять состояние